# How to get data from html table by specific <th> then compare <td> 's if matching color it?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to color every cell in a HTML table if it has same data in the table, but I want to do this only in a specified column not on the whole table.

| BRAND | TYPE | COLOR | BRAND | TYPE | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ford | Fiesta | white | Audi | A7 | black |
| Ferrari | F40 | red | Honda | Accord | silver |
| Ford | Fiesta | blue | Ford | Fiesta | yellow |

So for the example from above only Fiesta would get a green background in the table because I search only in TYPE columns

For debugging:

```js
// Function to color cells with matching values in the "NAME" column
function colorMatchingCells() {
  const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
  const nameCells = [];

  // Extract "NAME" column values
  for (let i = 2; i < cells.length; i += 10) {
    nameCells.push(cells[i].textContent);
  }

  // Compare and color matching cells
  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i += 1) {
    if (nameCells.includes(cells[i].textContent)) {
      cells[i].classList.add("green-cell");
    }
  }
}

// Call the function after the page loads
window.onload = colorMatchingCells;
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ind</th>
    <th>NUM</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
    <th>NUM</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
    <th>NUM</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">0</td>
    <td class="data">FORD</td>
    <td class="data">R39185</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">KIA</td>
    <td class="data">K29481</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">TOYOTA</td>
    <td class="data">C39259</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">1</td>
    <td class="data">FORD</td>
    <td class="data">R39186</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">KIA</td>
    <td class="data">R39185</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">TOYOTA</td>
    <td class="data">C39260</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">2</td>
    <td class="data">FORD</td>
    <td class="data">R39187</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">KIA</td>
    <td class="data">K46981</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">TOYOTA</td>
    <td class="data">R39185</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("data");`

With:

`const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td.data:nth-child(4n+4)');`

This will only select the forth `td` instead of whole data class.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .green-cell {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ind</th>
    <th>NUM</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
    <th>NUM</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
    <th>NUM</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>TYPE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">0</td>
    <td class="data">FORD</td>
    <td class="data">R39185</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">KIA</td>
    <td class="data">K29481</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">TOYOTA</td>
    <td class="data">C39259</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">1</td>
    <td class="data">FORD</td>
    <td class="data">R39186</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">KIA</td>
    <td class="data">R39185</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">TOYOTA</td>
    <td class="data">C39260</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="data">2</td>
    <td class="data">FORD</td>
    <td class="data">R39187</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">KIA</td>
    <td class="data">K46981</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
    <td class="data">TOYOTA</td>
    <td class="data">R39185</td>
    <td class="data">MSOME</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  // Function to color cells with matching values in the "NAME" column
  function colorMatchingCells() {
    // const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td.data:nth-child(4n+4)');
    const nameCells = [];

    // Extract "NAME" column values
    for (let i = 2; i < cells.length; i += 10) {
      nameCells.push(cells[i].textContent);
    }

    // Compare and color matching cells
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i += 1) {
      if (nameCells.includes(cells[i].textContent)) {
        cells[i].classList.add("green-cell");
      }
    }
  }

  // Call the function after the page loads
  window.onload = colorMatchingCells;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```